NMOS based negative load switch schematic
I designed this switch to supply negative a -12 V, 2 A to Rload, based on  IPB072N15N3 G NMOS. The 3.3 V control signal to the FODM8801C optocoupler is provided by a microcontroller. Reverse current is not an issue, so one power MOSFET is enough.
I'm not experienced with negative supplies load switches. Is there any serious drawback or error with my design?


I am assuming the microcontroller ground is isolated from the power ground, and in that case it seems ok. Of course you could add some filtering and decoupling, but i also think you omitted it for simulation purposes.

The circuit looks OK to me.
The FET model IPB072N15N3 is an overkill for the 2 A load current, but it will work.
I would prefer 10-20 kΩ as R2 to provide faster turn off. This is not an issue using this large FET.
Because the gate capacitance is above 5 nF, the circuit allows only very slow PWM or static switching.

Refer to the FODM8801 datasheet, to find these data:

CTR \$\frac{I_C}{I_{LED}}\$ could be as low as 100% (C model) or 35% (A model)

LED forward voltage could be as high as \$V_F=+1.8V\$


These values will ultimately decide the resistor values in your design. The existing values will work, but you are not leveraging the opto-isolator's collector current for best performance.
I'll assume you're happy with \$R_5=1k\Omega\$, which will produce LED current at least:
$$ I_{LED} = \frac{+3.3V - V_F}{R_5} = \frac{+3.3V - 1.8V}{1k\Omega}  = 1.5mA $$
Worst case collector current will be:
$$ I_C = CTR \times I_{LED} = 100\% \times 1.5mA = 1.5mA $$
\$I_C\$ would no doubt be much higher (given the opportunity to rise that far), but it's best to design for worst case. It's also wise to cut that figure in half, just in case, so \$I_C\approx 0.8mA\$. I feel its a waste to not use that current to switch the MOSFET as fast as possible. As is stands, R1 and R2 are sub-optimal.
My thinking goes like this; you have an 11V zener diode clamping \$V_{GS}\$, which is never a bad idea, but it shouldn't really be invoked unless needed, to keep current through it to a minimum. We should size R1 and R2 to pass 0.8mA, with 11V across R2 and the remaining 1V across R1:
$$ R_1+R_2 = \frac{12V}{0.8mA} $$
$$ \frac{R_2}{R_1} = \frac{11V}{1V} $$

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
These are ideal figures, but you don't need to be that precise. Your existing \$R_1=1k\Omega\$ is fine, really, but you can drop R2 to \$R_2 \approx 15k\Omega\$. This will maximise gate current, and minimise switch-off time.

If you're not using the optocoupler's isolation, then it's not necessary to deal with the drawbacks like low CTR issues etc. Here's a suggestion:

First schematic uses a common base transistor. When "3v3_INPUT" goes high to 3V3, a current of 1mA flows through R3 then R2 and results in a 10V gate drive voltage for the MOSFET. The other schematic uses Q2 as current source, it has an inverting (active low) input. When the input goes to 0V, Q2 will source 1mA into R4 and turn on the MOSFET.
It is possible to slow down the MOSFET switching by adding G-D capacitance. This may be useful if the load has a lot of capacitance and that causes inrush current issues.
